# Unable to access JSON object by property in firebase via axios.get

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux, axios

I have created a call to a database from a redux action file, it always returns an empty object. The data for a given day of tasks is nested inside a date Object in JSON, I am trying to acces only the tasks that a given user posted to the Firebase DB.

I can authorize users to pull from Firebase without asking for specific tasks, but when using the query parameters (see the axios call) below it returns:

```
 {}
```

And nothing more.

The axios.get call in the redux actions file

```
export const fetchTasks = (token, userId) => {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch( fetchTasksStart(token, userId));
    const queryParams = '?auth=' + token + '&orderBy="userId"&equalTo="' + userId + '"';
    axios.get('./tasks.json' + queryParams)
      .then( response => {
        const fetchedTasks = [];
        for (let key in response.data) {
          fetchedTasks.push( {
            ...response.data[key],
            id: key
          } );
        }
        console.log(response.data);
        dispatch(fetchTasksSuccess(fetchedTasks));
      } )
      .catch(err => {
        dispatch(fetchTasksFail(err));
      } );
  };
};
```

The JSON data on the Firebase DB

```
  {
    "tasks" : {
      "20181025" : {
        "-LPelcWwUK2vB2mxqETB" : {
          "date" : "20181025",
          "end" : "2018-10-25T10:30:30.113Z",
          "hours" : 0,
          "minutes" : 0,
          "name" : "a",
          "seconds" : 2,
          "start" : "2018-10-25T10:30:28.521Z",
          "token" : "placeholder",
          "userId" : "placeholder"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Firebase Rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "tasks": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null",
    ".indexOn": ["userId"]

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Before jumping into axios - is there a reason you're not using the Firebase functions for this to get a snapshot back with the data?

Comment: Not any particular reason no, axios is just what I am familiar with.

Comment: @Joe-NewNine the calls I am making to Firebase are asynchronous, other than that I took a MOOC recently and axios was what was used.